# Autocomplete/Intellisense not working for dart/flutter in VSCode

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, intellisense

Even with the `CTRL+SPACE` shortcut, the options I get are nowhere near relevant to the code.

I created a new file named `questions.dart` in the lib folder along with `main.dart`. In `main.dart` the code autocomplete works fine but in `question.dart`, it doesn't. Also, the syntax is not getting highlighted as well in the new file.

For `questions.dart` [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCHkJ.png]

For `main.dart` [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJ96q.png]

Comment: You probably need to have typed something yourself. Try putting in the import material.dart line of code. There is no syntax to highlight in the questions.dart file you show, it is an empty file.

Comment: I added a few lines of code but still nothing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Restart the Dart Analysis Server. If that doesn't work, restart your IDE.

This happens to me occasionally. I believe it's an issue with the Dart Analysis Server. Usually, restarting the Dart Analysis Server fixes it.

To restart the Dart Analysis Server. Press `ctrl + shift + p`. Then search look for a command called `Dart: Restart Analysis Server`. If it doesn't work restart your IDE.

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the same issue here. I managed to solve it by **switching flutter channel from master to beta**. Now autocomplete works, but sometimes things still get crazy.